# representation of any number in power of '2' using PHP

Tags: php, recursion, timeout, design-patterns

I tried to play with php,however I got stuck at one place, where I tested value of $n=1024, then it takes more than 60sec,so timeout error of php arises,I don't know how to overcome this problem,if my only requirement is to present any input number in the 2<sup>0</sup> + ---+  2<sup>n</sup> Form.
trying below code with n=121,I got this,but I wish to represent 57 also in 2<sup>n</sup>
 Form,So I tried recursion,which didn't worked.

> see how a given no. be represented in powers of '2':
>   2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> +
>   2 + 2<sup>4</sup>+ 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>6</sup>+ 57

**CODE:**

```
<?php

echo("see how a given no. be represented in powers of '2' :<br/>\n");

$n=121;
$two_pow=array(
    pow(2,0),pow(2,1),pow(2,2),pow(2,3),pow(2,4),pow(2,5),
    pow(2,6),pow(2,7),pow(2,8),pow(2,9),pow(2,10)
);
//print_r($two_pow);


$i=0;

while($n>=$two_pow[$i])
    $i++;

/* displaying  2^3*/
if($i>0)
    $ij=$i-1;

/* diplaying difference of give N and 2^i*/
$diff=$n-$two_pow[$ij];

if($n>0)
{
    for($i=0;$i<=$ij;$i++)
    {
        echo("2<sup> $i </sup>"."+ \n");

        if($i==$ij && $diff>0)
        {
            echo("\n". $diff);
        }
    }
}
else 
    echo("<br/>not possible for values less then zero");

?>
```

Comment: Well, yes, this is going to take time to compute! What else were you expecting? And why did recursion "didn't worked"? What's the question here?

Comment: you need to suggest program modification,which allow to represent any number whether it is 1 or greater then 1024 also. and at the end,when whatever difference is left,wish to represent that also in 2^n form,I don't know the correct recursion to implement,so I'm here to ask experts like you all.

Comment: down voting is sometimes gives abusive feel,so avoid that,if you can't answer the correct code to accomplish task.

Comment: Nonsense. I will downvote an answer if it is worthy of being downvoted. My knowledge has nothing to do with it. Your reverse psychology will not work on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for recursion or anything like that, just convert to binary and loop through the characters:

```
$bits = array_reverse(str_split(decbin($n)));
$output = array();
foreach($bits as $key => $bit) {
    if($bit == 1) {
        $output[] = '2<sup>'.($key).'</sup>';
    }
}
echo implode(' + ', $output);
```

Working example:

> http://codepad.org/plzvw2RL

Comment: have you run this code,it posses the same timeout issue and gives 2^10 when n=512,but nice to know new to way solve same task.

Comment: It doesn't have any timeout issues, there's nothing heavy to calculate so if it hangs, the reason is elsewhere. And what is the expected output with n=512? 2^10 is the only way to represent that number.

Comment: when I tried again with n=1024,it takes more than 60 sec,so timeout occurred, and n=512 is to be represented as 2^9,not as 2^10,which is for n=1024

Comment: I have updated the example to give correct results. As you can very clearly see from the codepad link, the script does not take more than 60 seconds to execute. Remove all other code and try again, there is nothing computationally expensive in that example.

Comment: I also tried something using base convert method,which I listed here:http://demlaip.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/number-representation-in-2s-power-using-php/  And I try your solution also,its godd to know another method to do same thing..

Answer (score 2):

Cant you use - [base_convert()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) to convert the string to binary, then format your output based on the position of bits?

Answer (score -1):

It is a joke right?
Oh it isn't?
Well ok
take look at [decbin function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php). Isn't it easier?

Comment: if you think its a joke,don't laugh please,present the code to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: @Demla Pawan: please do not feel offended :) it just so much easier to convert your number from DEC to BIN and then parse result by just puting 2^i if 1 :)

Comment: @Demla: You ought to stop telling people what to do when asking for free help.

Comment: @mkk :  there's nothing like that,thanks for it,I'm trying ur suggestion.

Comment: @Tomalak : In order to get what you want,you have to elaborate what you actually want,that's what I learned in my colleges,so don't feel offended,I'm extremely thankful to this site and people of here,including you man.

Answer (score -3):

You can overcome the timeout restriction by [disabling the timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: is this really the fix for the problem? if there is a timeout in something like this,  I believe that the whole approach is wrong

Comment: so ,instead of suggesting to change environment parameters,you can suggest me the correct code to get the task done.

Comment: The number of times in my day job i find people think the solution to something taking ages is to increase a timeout! Unreal!

Comment: @diagonalbatman: It's not a solution to the algorithm taking ages. It's the solution to the algorithm not being allowed to run its course. This algorithm will take time: you will want to remove the timeout. If you can _also_ speed it up, then great!